# Cannot maximize application after it was minimized

Tags: vb.net

After many tries and tribulations I was able to finally minimize my application from a winform button. The code works perfectly:

```
    Private Sub btnMinWindow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMinWindow.Click

    'This procedure runs when the btnMinWindow is clicked.
    'The procedure minizmizes the form and Excel.


    Dim WB As Excel.Workbook = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)

    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    WB.Application.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMinimized

End Sub
```

So of course, what is minimize eventually needs to be maximize. So I assumed that all I had to do was right the same code only use xlMaximized. Of course, my assumption was wrong. here is my code:

```
    Private Sub btnMinEmployeeDashboard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMinEmployeeDashboard.Click

    'This procedure runs when the btnEmployeeDashboard button is clicked.

    Dim WB As Excel.Workbook = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
    WB.Application.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized
    WB.Sheets("employeeBoard").Select()

    Me.Close()


End Sub
```

The code closes the form, selects the sheet, but it does not maximize my window. I think that what I have to do is to make the variable that has it "already minimize" available (in scope) to the button _Click handler and use it instead of declaring a new variable. Unfortunately, if that is the case, I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Is this VB.net and you are using your application to do Office Interop (interacting with MS Excel)?  Or is this **VBA** and is a macro within Excel? They are different things. It would be helpful to know that, and maybe a little background information what your app does / how it works. What you've shown now is somewhat confusing without that.

Comment: @jonathon I am using vb net and soon office interop. Basically I have a form that acts as a start page for the workbook. The work starts minimized but when I click the button my form to select a sheet is suppose max the workbook but it does not

Comment: Unless I'm totally mistaken, You're either using "Office Interop in VB.net (Visual Studio)" or you're using "VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) within Excel itself". Which is it?

Comment: Sorry there was a misspelling. I meant say that I am using vb net to do office. So I am using office interop. I was writing from my iPhone so it autocorrected the words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I was able to find the code to get this to work. Here it is:

```
 Public Class Form1

    'Declare functions and constants
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Integer
    Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As Integer = 3


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Specify part of the window title you want. Get its window handle:
        Dim hwnd As String = findPartialTitle("Notepad")

        'Send hwnd to showwindow function
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)

    End Sub

    'FUNCTION: Find handle by partial window title
    Private Function findPartialTitle(ByVal partialTitle As String) As IntPtr
        For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
            If p.MainWindowTitle.IndexOf(partialTitle, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
                Return p.MainWindowHandle
            End If
        Next
        Return IntPtr.Zero
    End Function

End Class
```

http://www.techusers.net/60/how-maximize-external-application-window-title-vbnet

Answer (score 0):

Try to instance the Excel object to a class/module/global variable, then use this variable to perform actions on the Excel file while it remains opened.